# Getting the ID from a read request in Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: javascript, ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement a server-side script for one of my tables in Windows Azure Mobile Services. Currently, my script look like this:

```
function read(query, user, request) {

    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM nextjet.aircraft AS ac ' +
                'INNER JOIN nextjet.aircraft_type AS act ' +
                'ON ac.aircraft_type_id = act.id AND ac.id = ?';

    console.log('Attempting to fetch an aircraft row');

    mssql.query(sql, [request.id], {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log('aircaft row fetched: ' + results);
            request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('There was an error when fetching an aircraft row: ' + err);
            request.respond(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, 'The aircraft was not found in the database');
        }
    });
}
```

If I'm calling this from iOS with the method readWithId:(NSNumber *)id, how can I get the ID on the server side? As it is now (just trying to get it from the `request` object by calling `request.id`. This won't work, the log tells me that it's an invalid parameter type.

So, how do I get the ID? In an insert operation, I'll get access to the full object by the `item` object, but not in a read operation.

Thanks in advance,
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the ID you've sent in from readWithId, you need to use the **query** object that is a parameter to the read script.  In this case you'll use **query.id**.